# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) power consumption: Connected x Periodic connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery

I'm creating a mobile app that connects to a bluetooth low energy sensor to read its data every x minutes and power saving on the sensors's side battery is one of my concerns. I thought of two ways to do so:

A. Periodically connect to the sensor, read the data I want, then disconnect. Keep doing it every x minutes
B. Establish the connection, keep it constantly connected and only read the data every x minutes.

Which way should be the best with energy efficiency in mind regarding the sensor's battery?

In other words, would it consume more of the BLE sensor's battery to A)establish and terminate the connection 60 times in one hour or B)connect, keep it alive for 1 hour and disconnect after?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go forward would be to run battery tests with both method A and B. Getting battery data shouldn't be too much work, you can create your own small little app or use one on the Play Store.

Another thing to keep in mind is WakeLocks. Are you utilizing wakelocks for method B? If yes then any battery savings you might get from using BLE go out the window.

Comment: I'm not sure if your suggestion is practical. I would need to wait days or maybe months to learn how much battery options A and B consume, so I was actually looking for an answer or insight from someone who has done something similar before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I run battery tests on a daily basis for WiFi drains. Doesn't really take more than a couple of hours. Leave it overnight and you can check in the battery statistics as well.
Granted its not BLE but the process is the same in my opinion.

Comment: The BLE sensor I'm using takes weeks to show any significant drop of battery level.

Comment: Then there should be minimal difference between using the two options above as is. The difference then lies in your setup to connect/disconnect or stay connected to the receiver.

Comment: For example, if staying connected requires your CPU to be awake all the time, it will definitely drain the battery at a higher rate.

Comment: I just updated the question. I'm actually curious about the sensor's battery instead of the phone's battery or CPU usage. The sensor uses a "coin" battery that normally lasts a couple of years.

Comment: Ahh ok. My answer was based on the assumption that you were talking about the phone, not sensor